# Jsf validation with composite component is not working properly

Tags: java, validation, jsf, composite-component

my english is not good,sorry about that.My question is about jsf validation.When my validation bean throws ValidatorException,my managed bean save_method works.but i dont want that my save_method works.if email is not valid , my save_method shouldnt work.

composite interface

```
<composite:attribute name="validator" required="false"
        method-signature="void Action(javax.faces.context.FacesContext, javax.faces.component.UIComponent,Object)" />
```

composite implementation like that

```
<c:if test="#{cc.getValueExpression('validator')!=null}">
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
required="#{cc.attrs.required}" validator="#{cc.attrs.validator}"/>
```

validate method in validation bean.

```
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws    ValidatorException {
String email = (String) value;
Pattern mask = null;
mask = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_REGEX);
Matcher matcher = mask.matcher(email);

if (!matcher.matches()) {
    messageManager.warn(MessageManager.Bundles.WO, "validator.message.email");

   throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("hoppala"));
}
}
```

and my managed bean save method.

```
 @Override
    public boolean save() {
       super.save();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you working with mojarra below version 2.1.10? There [was a bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1806) that got fixed recently. So if you can, update to latest which is 2.1.13. But anyhow, in JSF you wouldn't do it the way you described it. I would recommend to apply the validator by using `<f:validator/>`, like this:

```xml
<mytags:customInput value="#{validationModel.value}">
   <f:validator for="input" validatorId="org.validationexample.EmailValidator" />
</mytags:customInput>
```

And your composite component would have to implement `<cc:editableValueHolder>`:

```xml
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="input" targets="inputText"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <p:inputText id="inputText" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

And finally your validation is handled by a dedicated validator class:

```java
@FacesValidator("org.validationexample.EmailValidator")
public class EmailValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        // your validation here
    }

}
```

Anyhow, there are other approaches/flavours as well. You can place `<f:validator>` also directly into your composite component inside `<p:inputText>`. Since `<f:validator>` has a `disabled` attribute you can disable it on demand.  Another approach would be to use Bean Validation and take the existing EmailValidator that comes with [Hibernate Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html_single/). In that case you just need to set the annotation @Email above your property.

Comment: +1 You beat me to this question.  Isn't it also possible though to use `<composite:renderFacet>` to insert the facet into the composite component as well?

Comment: @maple_shaft In case you mean using facets for optionally applying validators (?) - no. But maybe I understood wrong...